# Actionscript 3.0 Detect Camera Detachment

Tags: actionscript-3

All,
Could someone please tell me how to detect a camera detachment during video chat?Are there any events generated when camera is detached.
In our testing, there is no activity or camera status change event generated when a camer is detached.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe currentFPS should tell you if any frames are coming through.  It won't be an event, but you should be able to poll it for a while ...

[flash.media.Camera.currentFPS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#currentFPS)

Answer (score 0):

[Activity Event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#event%3aactivity) will help you to do that. You can check using `Camera.setMotionLevel()` and trigger the event. Hope this will help.